# What is libXinerama?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat

Can someone explain what it is in plain words?
I got some installation which required libXinerama. 
Eventually I got it working but I would like to know what it does 
and how it interacts with the rest of the system.

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Xinerama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) is an X11 extension which provides support for extending a desktop across multiple displays. (The name is a pun on [Cinerama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinerama), a widescreen movie format which used multiple projectors.)

The Xinerama extension is largely obsolete nowadays -- it has been replaced by the [RandR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) extension, which provides the same functionality on a more flexible basis. Some older programs still use the Xinerama interface, though, and the RandR extension provides a compatibility interface for these programs.

`libXinerama` is the library which interfaces with this extension.